# Setup RAID 0 on non-OS Drive in Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop

Tags: 20.04, raid, desktop-environments, nvme

I have Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop installed on a SATA SSD, but I would like to create a RAID 0 array out of 3 NVMe SSDs I have installed as well. I do not wish to install/move the OS onto the array, but simply have the array as a separate, fast storage space. After much searching, I am finding a lot about everything other than this scenario. Is mdadm the best tool for this? Or is there something easier? I’m relatively new, and while I can follow good CLI tutorials, the easier the better for me. I’m not looking for a tutorial (but would turn one down either), but rather, is Mdadt the best tool here? Note this is Ubuntu desktop. I can easily reinstall the OS if that is better or needed for some reason, so that is not off the table.

Thank you.

Comment: A RAID 0 setup does boost the performance in most areas, but not as much as people might expect. There is generally a slight hit to access times, which can bite if you’re reading a bunch of tiny files. Is your goal write throughput or something else?

Comment: RAID 0 doesn't really make any sense in this context.  You might not get any real world improvement and you compound the risk of data loss and accelerate drive failure due to excessive writes.